# Bootstrap data table search and pagination not working when data is load from ajax call

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to working on bootstrap data table in Laravel. My data is load successfully  but data table search and pagination is not working.so please help me.

my Html code on page is like that

```html
<table id="example111" class="table table-striped nowrap www" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1">Sr.No.</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">Edit/Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="departmentlist" id="departmentlist111"></tbody>
</table>
```

my ajax call on page like that

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#example111').DataTable({
        paging: false,
    });

    table.destroy();

    $('#example111').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?= URL::to('show_department')?>",
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "post",
            "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"},
            "dataSrc": function (e) {
                $("#departmentlist111").html(e);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

my route call on page is like

```
Route::post('show_department','admin\DepartmentController@show_department');
```

my controller call

```php
public function show_department()
{
    $cartdata = '<tr>
                 <td class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1"> 1</td>
                 <td >South Indian</td>
                 <td class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <td class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1"> 1</td>
                 <td >South </td>
                 <td class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <td class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1"> 1</td>
                 <td> Indian</td>
                 <td class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 <td class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1"> 1</td>
                 <td >South Indian</td>
                 <td class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                 </td>
                 </tr>';

    echo json_encode($cartdata);        
}
```

so please solve my error please.

Comment: Why do you need the global `table`?

Comment: @Piterden i am just checking datatable with demo code.but its not working

Comment: This is not the correct way. Please have a look at Server side data tables. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi thanks for guide me..but its not possible if i am using this code and datatable  code is working

Comment: THat's what I am saying. this is not the correct way to load data using ajax in datatable.